# Catching signal from Python child process using GLib

Tags: c, signals, glib

I'm trying to control the way my cursor looks during certain points of my program execution. To be specific, I want it to be a "spinner" when a Python script is executing, and then a standard pointer when it's done executing. Right now, I have a leave-event-notify callback in Glade that changes the spinner when it leaves a certain area, but this is non-ideal since the user might not know to move the cursor and the cursor doesn't accurately represent the state of the program.

I have my Python program signalling SIGUSR1 at the end of execution. I am spawning the Python script from a C file using GLib's `g_spawn_async_with_pipes`. Is there any way to catch a signal from the child process that this creates? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `G_SPAWN_DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD` flag to `g_spawn_async_with_pipes()` and then call `g_child_watch_add()` to get a notification when your Python subprocess exits. You don’t need to bother with `SIGUSR1` if the process exits when it’s done.

It’s a bit hard to provide a more specific answer unless you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: I’ve actually been working on a minimum example, I’ll get that herr as soon as it’s ready :)